# DB2 SQL: fastest way to get lagged value of many columns

Tags: sql, db2, lag

There are many ways to get a lagged value of a certain column in SQL, e.g.:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columns_to_order_by),
    value
  FROM table
)
SELECT
  curr.value - prev.value
FROM CTE cur
INNER JOIN CTE prev on prev.rownum = cur.rownum - 1
```

,or:

```
select variable_of_interest 
               ,lag(variable_of_interest ,1) 
                    over(partition by
                    some_group order by variable_1,...,variable_n) 
                    as lag_variable_of_interest
from DATA
```

I use the second version, but my code runs very slow when "lagging" many variables, such that my code becomes:

```
select        variable_of_interest_1
              ,variable_of_interest_2
              ,variable_of_interest_3
                   ,lag(variable_of_interest_1 ,1) 
                        over(partition by
                        some_group order by variable_1,...,variable_n) 
                        as lag_variable_of_interest_1
                    ,lag(variable_of_interest_2 ,1) 
                        over(partition by
                        some_group order by variable_1,...,variable_n) 
                        as lag_variable_of_interest_2
                   ,lag(variable_of_interest_3 ,1) 
                        over(partition by
                        some_group order by variable_1,...,variable_n) 
                        as lag_variable_of_interest_3
    from DATA
```

I wonder, is this because each lag function must by its own partition and order the whole data set, even though the are using the same partition and order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about how DB2 optimizes such queries.  If it executes each lag independently, then there is  definitely room to improve the optimizer.

One method you could use is `lag()` with a `join` on the *primary key*:

```
select t.*, tprev.*
from (select t.*, lag(id) over ( . . . ) as prev_id
      from t
     ) t left join
     t tprev
     on t.id = tprev.prev_id ;
```

From what you describe, this might be the most efficient method to do what you want.

This should be more efficient than `row_number()` because the join can make use of an index.

Comment: This look brilliant, thank you very much! Can I just ask, is *id* what you call the primary key? I have not seen it before.

Comment: @Erosennin . . . `id` is whatever your primary key is in the data.

Comment: is it really supposed to be " t left join
     t tprev" ? where do you define tprev?

Comment: @Erosennin . . . It is a table alias.  That is how it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Db2 will only sort the data once, if all OLAP functions use the same `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY`. You can confirm this by looking at an explain plan.

```
create table data(v1 int, v2 int, v3 int, g1 int, g2 int, o1 int, o2 int) organize by row
;
explain plan for
select  g1
,       g2
,       o1
,       o2
,       v1
,       v2
,       v3
,       lag(v1) over(partition by g1, g2 order by o1, o2 ) as lag_v1
,       lag(v2) over(partition by g1, g2 order by o1, o2 ) as lag_v2
,       lag(v3) over(partition by g1, g2 order by o1, o2 ) as lag_v3
from
    data
;
```

will give the following plan (using `db2exfmt -1 -d $DATABASE`). You can see there is only one `SORT` operator

```
Access Plan:
-----------

    Total Cost:             14.839
    Query Degree:           4



      Rows 
     RETURN
     (   1)
      Cost 
       I/O 
       |
      1000 
     LMTQ  
     (   2)
     14.839 
        2 
       |
      1000 
     TBSCAN
     (   3)
     14.5555 
        2 
       |
      1000 
     SORT  
     (   4)
     14.5554 
        2 
       |
      1000 
     TBSCAN
     (   5)
     14.2588 
        2 
       |
      1000 
 TABLE: PAUL    
      DATA
       Q1
```

BTW If you post a question with a real SQL query (along with some DDL and some idea of the data volumes), we might be able to suggest things that could improve the performance of getting lagged values.  It is difficult to advise in detail without seeing a better example